# Object.keys not working in extension but working in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

When I try to run -

```
var colorSelectorElements = document.getElementsByName('color-selector');

var addInColorListFunctionKey = Object.keys(colorSelectorElements[0]).find(key => key.startsWith('__reactProps'));
```

in console it works and find the key with `__reactProps` but `Object.keys` return `[]` in mozilla extension.

Comment: Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`?

Comment: Please check the value of `colorSelectorElements` in the script like `console.log(colorSelectorElements)`.

Comment: It returns list of nodes @Malama

Comment: Object.getOwnPropertyNames is also empty :( @trincot

Comment: Please do an error analysis and perform each step individually in your second line.

Comment: colorSelectorElements is fine. I am able to solve issue by help of duplicate question link i.e using wrappedJSObject.